# I need to create custom quantity boxes for a product in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to achieve something like this.

http://www.specsavers.com.au/contact-lenses/monthly-disposables/air-optix-aqua

Im using wordpress 3.9.2 and wocommerce 2.11.

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the official WooCommerce Product Add-on? We use it a lot - gives you a lot more flexibility with product listings.

Take a look at http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply James. But can I see a demo of the premium plugin you mentioned because I can't buy a $49 plugin without making sure it fits my requirement.

Can you please suggest some demo link for the same

Comment: I'm not sure if they provide a demo Rahul - I read through the documentation to make sure it was what we needed before comitting. You can find the info at http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-add-ons/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: One More question james.
Would it also add the product in cart like it does on the reference url which i gave?

Try adding the product in the cart on the reference url and see the cart page.

I need the exact thing which is running on the reference url

Comment: I'm not sure 100% but if you're using product groupings it should work in a similar way. I would ask Woothemes directly if you have some specific needs, as the way we use WooCommerce is probably different and I don't want to give any false impressions that may not work.

Comment: According to my research, the reference url which I gave uses drupal. So I'm wondering if drupal has this feature then WordPress too should have something like this.